# Emulate a chapter heading style

Tags: chapters

is there anyone who can help me emulate this chapter heading style?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{3em}{2ex}{24ex}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\sffamily\Large}{\thechapter}{5ex}{}[\vspace*{4ex}\hrulefill]%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard. Is there a way to apply the same font used for the chapter name in the whole document?

Comment: @AlessioVuolo: yes. Just remove `\sffamily`in the code. I used it because the image in your post showed a sans font.

Comment: I meant: is there a way to use the font of the chapter (which I suppose is a sans font) in the whole document? In other words, can I apply the sans font used for the chapter even in sections and in all the other parts of the document ?

Comment: @AlessioVuolo: sorry, it seems I misunderstood your query. Yes it is possible: declare `\sffamily` in the preamble (for text) and load the `sansmath` package, then declare `\sansmath`  , which works like the ` \boldmath` declaration outside mathmode, and every  formula that follow wil be in  mathsf.